# enviar datos desde services a components

Tags: angular

estoy iniciando en angular y estoy tratando de construir un visor de películas con " themoviedb ", tratando de mostrar una lista de peliculas, que el API da como resultado, mi problema es que no he logrado pasar los datos que me retorna desde el services.ts al component.ts, espero me puedan ayudar muchas gracias

subo el código.

```
// -------------------------------------

// ---list-movie.component.ts

// -------------------------------------

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {ClientService} from '../../services/client.service'

@Component({

  selector: 'app-list-movie',

  templateUrl: './list-movie.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./list-movie.component.css']

})
export class ListMovieComponent implements OnInit {

  listMovie :any={}

  constructor(public clientesService: ClientService) { }

  ngOnInit(){

    this.getList()

    this.listMovie =this.clientesService.listMovie

    console.log(this.listMovie)

    
    
  }

    getList(){

    this.clientesService.getListMovie()
    
    
  }

}
```

Código del servicio de la forma que la estoy manejando
// -------------------------------------
// ---client.service.ts
// -------------------------------------

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ClientService {

  
  url_api = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

  api_key = '2e6a9c27b6a80358ab3fefa717e0e2e5';

  listMovie: any ={}
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  

  

  async getListMovie(){
     
     this.http
    .get(
      'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=2e6a9c27b6a80358ab3fefa717e0e2e5&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1'
    )
    .subscribe((data) => {
      
     console.log(data)
      this.listMovie=data
      return(this.listMovie)
    });

  }
}
```

[![respuesta del servicio][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhrRT.png

Comment: Hola y bienenvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo que te hagas un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas como funciona el mismo, ademas te sugiero que leas [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: te comento que no esta muy bien visto que publiques imagenes de tu codigo, esto se hace dificil ya que no se puede manipular tu codigo sino que hay que leerlo y escribirlo nuevamente y es muy tedioso, te invito a que publiques tu codigo para poder ayudarte